# how to find which line is missing "{" "}"

Tags: basic

I want to make a program like Missing Bracket Finder, and I make it, but I want the program to tell me which in line is missing { or }, I'm totally beginner, sorry for my bad english.

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If System.IO.File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
            MsgBox("Number '{':" & System.IO.File.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Count(Function(x) x = "{") & "    " & "Number '}':" & System.IO.File.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Count(Function(x) x = "}"), MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Info")
        Else
            MsgBox(TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "File not found." & vbNewLine & "Please verify the correct file name was given.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Open")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please learn about the Stack data structure. This is a classic problem solved by stacks.

Answer (score 0):

For the programming problem that you are trying to solve, I think it is best that you read the file line by line. For each line you read, you can just search for the index of either "{" and "}". If searching for the index yields none(-1) then you are missing either "{" or "}". You can look at the example code below. I did not write any error checking condition, so you would have to implement that on your own.

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim fileName As String = "test.txt"
        Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim lineNumber As Integer = 0
        Dim lineContent As String
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(fileName)

        while fileReader.Peek() <> -1
            lineNumber = lineNumber + 1 ' <-- Move this to the bottom to start at line 0.
                                        '     Otherwise, it currently start at line 1.
            lineContent = fileReader.readLine()
            if ( lineContent.indexOf("{") = -1 ) then
                Console.WriteLine("Line " + lineNumber.toString() + " missing { ")
            end if
            if ( lineContent.indexOf("}") = -1 ) then
                Console.WriteLine("Line " + lineNumber.toString() + " missing } " )
            end if
        end while
    End Sub
End Module
```

The below is the content of the test.txt file:

```
abc {}
buffer{
c}
d
```

Answer (score -2):

yes hi, 
This is an easy trick, common and used everywhere in those programs and debuggers. You just set a counter for each type of braces, add 1 when it's '{' and substract one on the opposite direction. Line you won't get, but approximate solution will work once you reach out negative values, you should always get 0 in the end and never have negatives. If you want line anyway, just only empty spaces. Count empty spaces and work out your braces counting along with that, but it's not recommended.

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: Let it one and half year from now, I believe it is not slightly the time for you. I can describe the solution as I said in one sentence, but the code is usually not one sentence at all.